# How to use SMAPE evaluation metric on train dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am using SMAPE (Symmetric mean absolute percentage error) evaluation metric.

Formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_mean_absolute_percentage_error

```
def smape(A, F):
    return 100/len(A) * np.sum(2 * np.abs(F - A) / (np.abs(A) + np.abs(F)))
```

I am using above function for calculating SMAPE.

Now I am trying to evaluate my model using SMAPE above code but I am not able to understand how to use it on train dataset for evaluation and then predict values for test dataset.

My code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Train and test data split 70-30 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

# Establish model
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1)

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Now how to use SMAPE with above randomforest regressor ? Should I use `model.score` i.e `model.score(X_test, y_test)` or `model.smape(X_test, y_test)`

If I use `model.score(X_test, y_test)` I am getting `-0.4678402626438` score. Please suggest me how to use SMAPE metric with my random forest regressor model.

Comment: Let's say ````y_pred = model.predict(x_test)````, then use ````smape(y_test,y_pred)````

Comment: @xyzjayne Ok so after `model.fit(X_train, y_train)` Instead of using `model.predict(x_test)` I should use `smape(y_test,y_pred)` am I right ?

Comment: You need to make a prediction and assign it to a variable; otherwise you have nothing to compare against in the SMAPE...

Comment: @xyzjayne If possuble can you write an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `model.fit(X_train, y_train)`:

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
print(smape(y_test,y_pred))
```

Comment: I have one question: I am getting score = 101.89120508979043 check screenshot -> https://imgur.com/a/S74JNOU But as my train dataset had 79k rows now how can I predict test dataset which has only 495 rows ?

Comment: I believe the range of SMAPE is (0,200) according to your formula. I don't understand the second part of the question -- are you suggesting that the samples are not being split correctly (70 - 30)? https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/smape/

Comment: No you did not got my point. I am saying after training model on train dataset now I want to make predictions on test dataset (not test data from train-test split). How to make predictions on test dataset which has only 495 rows (i,e target variable should be predicted)

Comment: y_pred_1 = model.predict( ** whatever test dataset ** ) I guess?

Comment: and then after that prediction again use `smape()` am I right ?

Comment: Yes, with the matching y_test data

Comment: Why y_test again because it is testdata where target variable is missing ? How can I get y_test there ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176424/discussion-between-stone-rock-and-xyzjayne).